# Self-study question on Confidence Interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

Good day everyone, I was making an attempt on a self-study question on Confidence Interval:

> The CEO of Micosaft Inc is considering the proposal of offering a child care program for its employees. As part of the feasibility study, the CEO wishes to estimate the mean weekly child-care cost of their employees. A sample of 60 employees who use child care reveals the following statistics:

[image]

> where xi is the weekly child-care cost of 1-th employees. Find a 95% confidence interval for the population mean.

***My attempt as follows:***

[image]

Unfortunately, my answer defers from the model answer of ***80 +_ 2.0111. Appreciate any guidance on where am I not doing right. I've looked at the question and my attempt multiple times without much success to find a way to correct it.

Comment: Although I cannot reproduce the "correct" answer, I can get close ($2.008$) by using a Student t distribution with $60-1$ degrees of freedom instead of a Normal distribution. Is the Student t also covered in this study material?

Comment: @whuber yes sir, it is. Studentized T Distribution is something I've read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several minor errors here that will lead you into problems.

1) the sample standard deviation is *not* $\sigma$. By convention, Greek letters are for population parameters not sample quantities. You computed $s_{n-1}$, not $\sigma$. Call it $s$ and you won't be so likely to mislead yourself into:

2) You're using Z tables. You don't know $\sigma$, you estimated it, so you're dealing with a t-distribution as the basis for the interval*, not a normal distribution.

In this case (n=60) the distinction between the two isn't terribly large, but if you want to understand what you're doing, always treat $t$ as $t$ until the final step, even if $n$ is in the hundreds (that is, only bring the approximation of $t$ by a normal in at the very end, to help keep the concepts clearly distinct).

* specifically, the pivotal quantity from which the interval is derived has a t-distribution

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Based on whuber's pointing out that you do not have the data, I get your result for the variance (it was in an unfamiliar form), but when we use the *t* distribution as whuber inquires after I get exactly the text's answer:

$s_{\bar{x}} = 1.00507$

$t_{\alpha/2,\text{ }\nu=59} = 2.00100$

95% CI: $80 \pm 2.01114$

Comment: many thanks for your rapid reverts. I have attempted to use the above formulae, but I am still getting at the exact same output. I was wondering if there's anything fundamentally with how I did my standard deviation calculations? I've shared my working via http://picpaste.com/pics/image-12hEwqZw.1398713163.jpg

Comment: You have not used my formula: $\sum^{n}_{i=1}{(x_{i}−\bar{x})^{2}} \ne n(\sum^{n}_{i=1}{x_{i}})^{2}−x^{2}$. The difference of two squares is not the square of the differences. You may recall: $(x−a)^{2}=x^{2}−2ax+a^{2}$ In this case, you need to manually calculate $x_{i}−\bar{x}$ and square it, do this sixty times, add that up. Then proceed with your CIs.

Comment: In addition, there's possibly a learning opportunity for you here: $(x_{i} - \bar{x})$ is the *deviation* of observation $x_{i}$ from the mean ($\bar{x}$). If you stare at the variance formula, you'll see that the variance is more or less the (artithmetic) *mean* of squared deviations (i.e. add up the number of squared deviations, and divide by the number of squared deviations, or, for the sample variance, divide by $n-1$, because of sampling uncertainty).

Comment: Alexis, I fear you may be leading the OP astray. Notice he has only the sum and sum of squares of the data; therefore an algebraically equivalent expression for the variance estimator is needed--and he is using a correct one and appears to be computing with it correctly.  (Your first comment seems to overlook the fact that $\sum_i \bar{x} x_i = 0$ when computing the sum of squares of residuals.)

Comment: Hmmm you may be correct there, I missed that he didn't have the actual data. While $\sum{\varepsilon_{i}}=0$ I don't think $\sum{\bar{x}x} = 0$, for example: $x \in \{1,2,3\}$, $\bar{x} = 2$, $\bar{x}x \in \{2,4,6\}$, and $\sum{\bar{x}x}=12 \ne 0$

Comment: You're right: I meant to write that $\sum\bar{x}(x_i-\bar{x})=0$. With that in mind you need to replace the "$\ne$" in your first comment with an "$=$" (assuming that by "$x$" you meant "$\bar x$").  Nevertheless, thank you for checking the calculation and big +1 for editing your answer to help the O.P.!